# Mysql Update where Count Distinct return more than one row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, the first one with a list of guides names, chapter and topic, that change with time when new guides are added with or without the same name, lets called "guides", sort of this:

```
|---Name---|---Chapter---|---Topic---|
|The Hearth| 1           |Educational|
|The Hearth| 2           |Educational|
|The Hearth| 3           |Educational|
|The Brain | 1           |Maths      |
```

and another table where i assign a ID to each guide, lets called "resume", something like this

```
|---id---|---Name---|---Topic---|
| 1      |The Hearth|Educational|
| 2      |The Brain |Maths      |
```

Now when a guide of the same name is added to "guides" and it have a dif topic, like:

```
|---Name---|---Chapter---|---Topic---|
|The Hearth| 4           |Tales      |
```

i need to update the "resume" table to:

```
|---id---|---Name---|---Topic---|
| 1      |The Hearth|MIXED      |
| 2      |The Brain |Maths      |
```

i have been trying different ways and this is what i have so far:

```
UPDATE resume J INNER JOIN guides P ON J.name = P.name SET J.topic = "Mixed" 
WHERE     J.topic != P.topic AND (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.topic)
FROM     guides a
JOIN   guides   b
ON a.name = b.name
AND a.topic != b.topic     
GROUP BY a.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.topic) > 1)
```

All is ok while there is just one record, but if there was added two guides with dif topics the subquery returns more than one row and it dont make the update. I know i can solve this with a php loop, but im sure there must be a way to handle this on the query itself, i would appreciate any lights on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a select count first and join later to optimize the query speed:

```
UPDATE resume J
INNER JOIN (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.topic) AS num, A.name
FROM guides A 
GROUP BY A.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT A.topic)>1) AS P ON J.name = P.name
SET J.topic = "Mixed"
```

Comment: This work perfectly! I didnt knew that was possible that way, my brain still is working on understand it lol. thanks chianh!